# "su" does not work on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, shell, su

Below I sun "su" command on FreeBSD:

```
FreeBSD rand.vstyle.local 9.0-RELEASE FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE #0 amd64

This is server RAND :)

[svn@rand ~]$ su logostudiotest1 /bin/ls
Password:
/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
```

Why "su" does not work?!

Comment: Silly question, maybe, but can you run /bin/ls as any other user?

Answer (score 14):

According to the [su manpage](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=su&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+2.2.8-RELEASE&format=html) if you want to run a command as another user using `su`, you should use the `-c` switch.

For example: `su logostudiotest1 -c /bin/ls`

Comment: Yeah, this. The command given in the question won't work on Linux either.

Comment: `ls` makes a lousy shell.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've confused su with sudo.  This should work fine:

```
# sudo -u logostudiotest1 /bin/ls
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the problem while using chroot'ed 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit version of FreeBSD.

At first I thought something with ldconfig -32 might help, but than I noticed it
was using PAM and/or several other authentication scheme that older programs
didn't know.

I ended up just writing short C programs to chain the user shells or whatever
else I needed to run, and then chmod'ed them to 4550 and used the group number (guid)
to prevent unauthorized access  to those programs.  I could have also just programmed
in a hard-coded password or whatever.